# Where to bind API and templates routes in webapp?

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, backbone.js

So, I come forward with this question as a Django developer, since in Django we have the very useful template tags (and functions) `reverse` and `static`.

I have been trying to find similar approaches for frameworks like Angular or Backbone, with no luck. We end up having hard references that I would like to avoid.

I've been thinking about keeping a file with all the routes as JS constants but it feels like a rookie approach. What is a reasonable and broad take on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding reverse, there's a similar feature in AngularJS, by using ui-router (instead of traditionnal AngularJS router).

You can define url aliases then use $state.go('your_alias') to go to the good url with js code.

In the html code, you can use ui-sref="your_alias" for the same purpose.

This also works with parameters, cf :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1

and :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Moreover, you can access state infos (alias/parameters/etc...) from within controllers, which can be very useful

Comment: Yes, we use that for states in Angular and that really works great with states. 
I was wondering more about the API that backs your app.